# Where should I start reading AngularJS's source code?

Tags: source-code, reading-code, angularjs

After reading [this article](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/code-reading/) I realized that I really didn't read any "serious" source code during my 3-years as a professional developer.

Recently I started a new web-project which makes heavy use of AngularJS, so I decided to start my reading - or, better, *decoding* [as the blogger wrote] - activity from something that is both challenging and professionally useful.

Now I just need to be pointed in the right direction. Should I just start from the start of the source code or is there a better starting point?

Comment: recommended reading: **[Where to start](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260)**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For AngularJS, I think the best place to start is `$scope.$apply()`, as this ties together changes to the model and the view. From there, move to one of the simpler directives, perhaps `ng:value`.

Keep the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts) open while you're doing this.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, nice suggestion (sorry can't upvote).

Answer (score 1):

For AngularJS :
Prerequisites ::
1) Firstly you need have good hands over on **JAVASCRIPT patterns** like revealing pattern, prototype pattern, model pattern and prototype revealing pattern.
2) Go through **MVC framework concepts** how does this works. Taking server side MVC frameworks like **MVC3/MVC4.**

Going through above steps first will be added advantage while understanding angularjs :: **Directives, structure **and** work flow.**
 Greatest source for learning AngularJS concepts is  **https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts**

Lastly  **http://plnkr.co/** this is greatest online tool for editing and running angularjs application.